# Arabic and latin characters together

Tags: pdftex, arabic

Please have a look at this file I found online:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex} % Required for arab

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}% Set English as default
This is English

\foreignlanguage{arabic}{هذا عربي}
\end{document}
```

I'm generating documents in runtime so it's not feasible for me to wrap every arabic phrase with `\foreignlanguage{arabic}` what would you suggest me? Can I somehow achieve the following to render correctly? and if yes, with which packages/config.

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}% Set English as default
This is English هذا عربي
\end{document}
```

I'm using pdflatex but I'm open to change if that'd be the only way.

source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyordhel/UnicodeTexSnippets/master/templates/arabiyyah.tex

In my current setup I'm getting the following error, which is expected:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char و (U+648)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

since this input comes from the user I can't do the normally suggested find and replaces with commands, I need a generic solution.

Comment: How about `lualatex`?  this can be done  with `babel` (from version 3.23) using option 
`bidi=basic`.

Comment: @SalimBou I will give it a try, thanks for the tip.